# Only override type annotations of inherited methods in python

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding, python-typing

```py
class Root:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    def config(self, **kwargs):
        ...

class A(Root):
    def __init(self, a, b, c):
        self.a, self.b, self.c = a, b, c

    def config(self, a, b, c):
        ...

class B(Root):
    def __init(self, a, d, e, f):
        ...

    def config(self, a, d, e, f):
        ...
```

I have two classes, which inherit from Root. They have partially different attributes. I have a  config method to change these attributes in the Root Class. I now want to override only the annotations for each of the subclasses. The config method works for both classes, and I don't want to implement it twice. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36306834/how-to-type-annotate-overrided-methods-in-a-subclass) question, which is basically the opposite of what I want to do.

Comment: Your code has no annotations; did you mean "signature"? It's impossible to answer this without knowing what `config` in all three cases is supposed to do, but I suspect the duplication of `a` and `b` in the subclass methods is already a problem.

Comment: `A.__init__` should probably only define `c` as an explicit parameter, passing any other arguments to `super().__init__`; same goes for `B.__init__` and `e`/`f`. Perhaps `config` should likewise be using `super().__config__` to let each class handle the attributes it "owns"?

Comment: @chepner I mean both annotations and and arguments, like what @ overload does, except its defined after the 'real' implementation. The config method is basically setattr, except it does multpie attrs at once an handles special cases, where more than setattr is needed. Also the Root class does define a in practice, this is just a generalized example.

Comment: Doesn't matter how you define `config` - the situation you describe violates LSP if `config` on parent is typed stronger than `Callable[..., None]`, because there is no such `some_args_known_in_advance` sequence that allows you to call `child.config(<some_args_known_in_advance>)` given only the fact that `child` is any instance of `Root`.  Type checkers allow this violation only for `__init__` method by convention, because it is useful too often.